# Pass the range to a Table as a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Potentially very silly question here.

What I have:

```
xaxis = {r, 0, 3}
```

And if I do:

```
Plot[r^2, xaxis]
```

it works.

I'd like to the same for a `Table`, i.e. defining its paratemers (range, step etc.) elsewhere and then just importing them, like so:

```
Table[r, Append[xaxis, 0.1]]
```

where the `0.1` there is the step I am taking.

This does not work however! 
 Is it not possible at all? 
 Do I have to define it like  `Table[r, {r,0,3,0.1}]` ?

Comment: `Table[r, Evaluate@Append[xaxis, 0.1]]`

Comment: That solved it, thanks. Any physical reason as to why this works and method did not?

Comment: `Table` has the attribute `HoldAll`

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity how do I know this? I couldn't find it mentioned on the documentation?

Comment: Evaluate `?? Table`

Comment: Oh nice, never new that! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to work with the syntax:

```
Table[body, {iter, values}]
```

instead. Then, you could use:

```
xaxis = Sequence[0, 3];
xiter = Range[xaxis];

(* Table *)

Table[x, {x, xiter}]
(* or *)
Table[x, {x, Range[xaxis]}]

(* Plot *)  
Plot[x, {x, xaxis}]
```

> {0, 1, 2, 3}
>
> {0, 1, 2, 3}

[image]

Your step version would be:

```
xiter = Range[xaxis, .1];

Table[x, {x, xiter}]
(* or *)    
Table[x, {x, Range[xaxis, .1]}]
```

> {0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 
>   1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2., 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3.}
>
> {0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 
>   1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2., 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3.}